# Bind-Param string MM/DD/YY to SQL Date object in a bind

Tags: php, string, date, mysqli, bind

I receive the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

My code is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $db_table(userFullName,userName,userExEmail,userPhone,userDOB) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            //Binding to Prevent SQL injection                      
            $requery = $mysqli_db->prepare($query);         
            $requery->bind_param("ssssss",$webmailFullName,$webmailUserName,$webmailExEmail,$webmailPhone,$webmailDOB);
```

I'm sure the problem is the field in MySQL called userDOB which is set a SQL date field on my webpage server.

The form which gives $webmailDOB is a jQuery ui datepicker widget which passes the date in MM/DD/YY.  As a post I think its passed as a string?

I think my problem is sssss?

I need to convert that last s to a date in the SQL format?

I don't know how to implement it so can someone show me the code needed to stop this error happening?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: Its been a long day, 6 S's

When I inspected my SQL database I noticed the date object was 0000-00-00 and was sent a number like 02/14/14?  I'm assuming SQL works in YYYY/MM/DD ?

Comment: In a long day it's a good idea to take a break. Especially in asking a question hastily for *any* error you get, without even reading it. Mysql date format is YYYY-MM-DD and, foreseeing your next question - there are more than thousand questions asked already, exactly on mysql date conversions. Please at least try to search first. It is not that hard.

Comment: From a previous comment of yours: "*On this site it is considered polite to close a duplicate question instead of writing an answer of your own, polluting site with thousands similar questions.*" -- What happened to that? Is this not a duplicate question?

Comment: @AmalMurali this is not an answer either.

Comment: Why not? It seems like an answer to me (which was made CW recently) :)

Comment: I think you've got it wrong; I read the error message perfectly; and knew I had the wrong amount of elements.  My mistake was assuming I had one less as I had my date object as a string.  I had missed multiple times the ssssss.  I'm kind of sure in my question I identified the part of the code which was causing problems, so it's clear I researched the strings as my previous question to this had no ssssss at all.  Im not convinced Amal it's polite to jump onto a beginners post asking anyone for help who's keen to learn saying its a duplicate.  In fact all questions answered I've +1 for others

Comment: May be it's due my poor English, but I can't get most of this latter message.